# Execution Time of Activity Callbacks

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, message, runnable

This may have been hidden somewhere in the docs, but I don't remember seeing it:

Assuming everything is running on the same thread, would an activity callback, or any kind of callback for that matter, interrupt a runnable , or even some other callback, executing on the thread, or are they posted sequentially by time of occurance as messages similar to runnables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly doesn't interrupt execution, at least in the UI thread. For instance, say that you have a Button, and you place a Thread.sleep(10000) in its onClick callback. Well, as soon as you press the button the entire UI will freeze. This wouldn't happen if the onClick callback interrupted the UI thread's execution.

Comment: I have just tested this using sleep in an Activity, and it seems that the messages do queue up properly with the exception that certain messages are lost if the thread is not active.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to know all the answer of the question you need to use

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Runnable.
All activity callbacks happen in the UI Thread. For example thread for onCreate is same as the thread which calls onTabSelected.

If you are started an AsyncTask, it runs in its own thread.

Try using following Log statement to check your scenario

```
Log.i("","Thread Id : "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
```